# I am trying to create login through pdo sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

I'm new to PDO and I'm trying to fetch data but every time i enter my details my getting wrong details error. My registration is workin perfect, but when i'm entering login details it's showing me wrong details. I am attaching code here.
connection file

```
class Database {   
    private $host = "*****";
    private $dbname = "*****";
    private $username = "*****";
    private $password = "*****";
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection() {
        $this->conn = null;    
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=" . $this->host . ";Database=" . $this->dbname, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        } catch(PDOException $exception) {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

my class

```
require_once('dbconfig.php');

class USER {    
    private $conn;

    public function __construct() {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }


    public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass) {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email,    user_pass FROM cust WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
            $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
                if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass'])) {
                    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

call to doLogin()

```
<?php
   session_start();
   require_once("class.user.php");
   $login = new USER();

   if($login->is_loggedin()!="")
   {
     $login->redirect('services.php');
   }

   if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
   {
     $uname = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
     $umail = strip_tags($_POST['txt_uname_email']);
     $upass = strip_tags($_POST['txt_password']);

     if($login->doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass))
     {
        $login->redirect('services.php');
     }
     else
     {
       $error = "Wrong Details !";
     }  
  }
?>
```

Comment: How are you saving the password? Are you using `password_hash()`?

Comment: Why are you making a new object of the db connection in the user class? It's easier to extend the db class in the user class.

Comment: I dont see a call to `doLogin()` anywhere. That might also be useful to see

Comment: What do you mean by _but when i'm entering login details it's showing me wrong details_??

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've added my call to doLogin(), when I'm trying to login the else part is only running, which is saying "Wrong Details" .

Comment: Read [this whole page in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) but specifically **Example #2**

Comment: @RiggsFolly - That example seems a bit overkill considering, in this case, the OP is just looking to see if a single row was returned - where something like an `if(!empty($userRow))` would possibly be sufficient, or even `if($userRow)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$stmt->rowCount()` does not return a valid result in some cases unless you run a `store_result()` before testing the number of row returned from a SELECT.

```
require_once('dbconfig.php');

class USER {    
    private $conn;

    public function __construct() {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }


    public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass) {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email,user_pass 
                                        FROM cust 
                                        WHERE user_name=:uname 
                                           OR user_email=:umail ");
            $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));

            // new line
            $stmt->store_result();

            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
                // moved inside if as no point reading result unless one exists
                $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass'])) {
                    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could just do

```
    public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass) {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email,user_pass 
                                        FROM cust 
                                        WHERE user_name=:uname 
                                           OR user_email=:umail ");
            $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));

            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if(!empty($userRow)) {

                if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass'])) {
                    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```